# Spring Cloud Gateway Programmatic Routing Issue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm using **Spring Cloud Gateway 2023.0.0** for implementing some routing programmatically. To start with, here is my RouteLocator bean configuration:

```
  @Bean
  public RouteLocator routeLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
        .route("some_id", p -> p.path("/reqres/**").uri("https://reqres.in"))
        .build();
  }
```

So to route to uri like **https://reqres.in/api/users/2**, I'm expecting whenever some request comes to my application with uri like **/reqres/api/users/2** then it should be routed correctly.

However, it's always returning 404 from https://reqres.in although the actual api i.e. https://reqres.in/api/users/2 is working just fine.

What's I'm doing wrong in here?

Comment: Please add your build configuration(pom/gradle) file.